# Is there any way to generate ROC curves from KEEL?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, algorithms, java

i am using the KEEL gui for my experiments . I want to plot a ROC curve of the results produced by KEEL rather than a just a roc score value [image: demo xml of my experiment] .